# Use Object.keys() instead of .length on Firebase Object

Tags: javascript, database, typescript

How to use Object.keys() to correct this snippet? When the comments ids are numbers the code works fine. Now How to make it  works with auto generated ids from firebase.

(Data structure is below)

```js
ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params     
.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishservice.getDish(params['id'])))
     .subscribe(dish => {
          this.dish = dish
          this.favorite = this.favoriteService.isFavorite(this.dish.id); 
          
          //compute the average of ratings and render the number of comments
          this.numcomments =  this.dish.comments.length;           
          let total =0; 
          this.dish.comments.forEach(comment =>total += comment.rating); 
          this.avgstars = (total/this.numcomments).toFixed(2); 
           },
          errmess => this.errMess = <any>errmess); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you correct the snippet ?

Comment: Start with `console.log(Object.keys(this.dish.comments))`. There's also Object.values() and Object.entries().

Comment: @Chris G So then? I am stack here for a while now. I would appreicate your appraoch. If you could refactor that code.

Comment: `this.dish.comments` is an object or array ?

Comment: Well, what's the output?

Comment: @ShijilNarayanan I was advised to consider it an Object and use Object.keys() to loop through it. But its an object If you consider it as part of the dish (0 here) which is in turn part of an array named dishes. Meanwhile its an array becasue it contains subobject. I am new  and still learning the basics. I would appreciate your help. As I said when I use numbers instead of the auto generated alphanumerics by firebase the above code works fine.

Comment: I have added an answer, please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const commentIds  = Object.keys(this.dish.comments);
this.numcomments =  commentIds.length;           
let total = 0; 
commentIds.forEach(commentId => total += this.dish.comments[commentId].rating); 
this.avgstars = (total/this.numcomments).toFixed(2);
```